# Force update array on Repeater

Tags: repeater, nativescript

When using XML to build an repeater, like the example above, how to update the array later?

```
        <Repeater items="{{ letras }}" id="rep">
        <Repeater.itemsLayout>
            <StackLayout horizontalAlignment="center" orientation="horizontal" />
        </Repeater.itemsLayout>
        <Repeater.itemTemplate>
            <Button text="{{ l }}" cssClass="palavraPrincipal" />
        </Repeater.itemTemplate>
        </Repeater>
```

I know that there is an way to do that if I create the repeater on Javascript file, but on a pre-made XML repeater?

Answer (score 1):

To make changes in the viewmodel (the `letras` array in your example) reflect in the UI you need to use [Native Script's data binding](http://docs.nativescript.org/bindings).

Below is an example which, given the XML view in your post, will:

1. Require the 2 modules, observable (for observable *objects*) and observable-array (for *arrays*).
2. Create a viewmodel, which is the object which holds the data
3. Bind the viewmodel to your page's binding context.
4. Every 1 second, add a new item to the viewmodel (which will get reflected to the UI).

I set the binding context of the *page* to the viewmodel. There's no need to set the binding context on the Repeater element, as calebeaires do in his example, as the Repeater will look at the page's binding context.

However, if you want to, you can use e.g. 2 different binding contexts, 1 for the page and one for the Repeater element. Just substitute

```
page.bindingContext = viewModel;
```

for

```
page.getViewById('rep').bindingContext = viewModel;
```

Full code:

```
var observableModule = require("data/observable");
var observableArrayModule = require("data/observable-array");

var viewModel = new observableModule.Observable({
    letras: new observableArrayModule.ObservableArray([
        { l: 'First' },
        { l: 'Second' },
        { l: 'Third' },
    ])
});

function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = viewModel;
    //page.getViewById('rep').bindingContext = viewModel;

    // Add a new item every 1 second.
    setInterval(function() {
        viewModel.letras.push({
            l: 'New item'
        });
    }, 1000);
}
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

Answer (score -1):

Find out:

A. Declare and variable:

```
var repeater;
```

B. Declare an ID to the repeater:

```
<Repeater items="{{ items }}" id="rep">
 <Repeater.itemTemplate>
     <Button text="{{ $value }}" />
 </Repeater.itemTemplate> 
</Repeater>
```

C. Redeclare it on page load:

```
function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    repeater = view.getViewById(page, "rep");
    page.bindingContext = jogo;
}
```

Comment: A couple of things wrong with this. OP asked to "update the array later" which needs you to utilize an observable object/array. Also, no need to getViewById. But *if* you want to set the view by id, in your example you need to define 'view' (or better, use getViewById on the 'page' variable). And 'jogo' should probably be 'repeater'